# Using extended multiple monitors in Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, kubuntu

I use [VirtualBox 4.3.12 r93733](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.12/):

- Guest OS: Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 x64
- Host OS: Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate

I configured the virtual machine to have 2 monitors:

[image]

When I launch Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 I do have 2 monitors, but they are cloned. I try to set 2 monitors to extended, but in *System Preferences -> Display and Monitor* I don't see any setting for that:

[image]

How to configure  Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4 to have extended multiple monitors?

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.